# React: How to add unique className?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How to add to `className - "i"`? To make each class unique? Or maybe it is done somehow differently? Tell me please?

```js
 const onHandleCreateBlockInfo = () => {
  return infoArray.map(i => {
    return (
      <div key={id++} className={i.keys()}>
  {i.company !== undefined ? <h2>Всего клиентов: {i.company.length}</h2> : null}
  {i.invoice !== undefined ? <h2>Оплаченных заказов: {i.invoice.length}</h2> : null}
  {i.projects !== undefined ? <h2>Открытых проектов: {i.projects.filter(i => i.status === true).length}</h2> : null}
  {i.users !== undefined ? <h2>Работников компании: {i.users.length}</h2> : null}
      </div>
    );
  })
};
```

This is not how it works (

Answer (score 2):

try `className={"myClassName"+index}` which is static part `myClassName` and adding the index to it; be sure to get the index inside map also. **Snippet** below:

```
  return infoArray.map((i, index) => {
return (
  <div key={index} className={"myClassName"+index}>
 {i.company !== undefined ? <h2>Всего клиентов: {i.company.length}</h2> : null}
 {i.invoice !== undefined ? <h2>Оплаченных заказов: {i.invoice.length}</h2> : null}
 {i.projects !== undefined ? <h2>Открытых проектов: {i.projects.filter(i => i.status === true).length}</h2> : null}
 {i.users !== undefined ? <h2>Работников компании: {i.users.length}</h2> : null}
  </div>
);
  })
```